# Passing screenshot from selenium into Pillow without saving to disk

Tags: python, selenium, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to take multiple screenshots using Selenium and need to do some basic image processing on each image and I'm using Pillow for this task.

I'm trying to reduce the number of read and writes so would like to pass the png straight from selenium into Pillow without saving it to disk first.

Below is a rudimentary example of what I'm trying to achieve however I can't pass the selenium png straight into the Pillow Image object so that step doesn't work.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
 
from PIL import Image
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager


driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
 
url = "https://www.google.com/"
 
driver.get(url)
 
temp = driver.get_screenshot_as_png()
 
image = Image(temp)

rgb = image.convert('RGB')
 
rgb.save("./")
```

Is this approach possible? Or is there an alternate solution that could implemented to reduce the writing to and reading from disk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, **get_screenshot_as_png** is not a method so no need to call it.

Second, [The documentation](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/3.0.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.open) for **Image.open** says that it can accept a file-like object, so you should be able to pass in a **io.BytesIO** object created from the bytes object containing the encoded image:

So you can use this code to read the image:

```
from selenium import webdriver
 
from PIL import Image
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import io #For Reading the Byte File retrieved from selenium


driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
 
url = "https://www.google.com/"
 
driver.get(url)
 
temp = io.BytesIO(driver.get_screenshot_as_png)
 
image = Image.open(temp)

# DO ANY ADDITIONAL THINGS AFTER

image.show()
```